# Segmentation fault accessing 2D array

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

I have a 2D array representing a sudoku grid defined like this:

```
int** sudoku = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*) * 9);
for(i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    sudoku[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 9);
```

I've run it through a function that iterates through every element and prints, which works fine (displays 81 zeros). But then, I hand it to another function that reads a grid from a file into this array. Here's what it looks like (with a bunch of printf statements I'm using for debugging omitted).

```
void readSudokuFile(char* filename, int*** grid) {
    FILE* file;
    int i, j, curr;

    file = fopen(filename, "r");
    for(i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            fscanf(file, "%d", &curr);
            *grid[i][j] = curr;
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

When the function is running, it appears to read find for the first row, but when it gets to the second row and tries to insert a value into sudoku[1][0], I get a seg fault. This is what the output looks like with my printfs in:

```
Reading line 0...
    Reading col 0... got 6
    Reading col 1... got 2
    Reading col 2... got 4
    Reading col 3... got 5
    Reading col 4... got 3
    Reading col 5... got 9
    Reading col 6... got 1
    Reading col 7... got 8
    Reading col 8... got 7
Reading line 1...
    Reading col 0... got 5
Segmentation fault(core dumped)
```

This is the file I'm trying to read in:

```
6 2 4 5 3 9 1 8 7
5 1 9 7 2 8 6 3 4
8 3 7 6 1 4 2 9 5
1 4 3 8 6 5 7 2 9
9 5 8 2 4 7 3 6 1
7 6 2 3 9 1 4 5 8
3 7 1 9 5 6 8 4 2
4 9 6 1 8 2 5 7 3
2 8 5 4 7 3 9 1 6
```

I'm compiling using gcc with -Wall and -pedantic, and am getting no compiler warnings.

I've googled around for a few hours to no avail, I'm not exactly sure what's going wrong here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: no need to cast your `malloc` return values. How are you calling this `readSudokuFile` function? Run valgrind on your code.

Comment: Change `*grid[i][j] = curr;` to `(*grid)[i][j] = curr;`. But really, `int sudoku[9][9]` would have made things a *lot* easier. And there's no need to pass a pointer to `grid` to this function, unless it's liable to reallocate the array at some point.

Comment: Completely forgot about valgrind! I'll have a look with it. I call the function with `readSudokuFile(argv[1], &sudoku)`

Comment: There is no 2D array in the code shown and nothing whch can point to one. A pointer is not an array. And being a 3-star (`***`) C programmer is not a compliment!

Comment: `(*grid)[i][j] = curr` is giving the same results. And I agree that `sudoku[9][9]` makes things easier, but this is for a multiprocess sudoku solution check and using that definition for the array while sharing it through shared memory proved problematic.

Comment: @rjt197197: There is no problem using an array. If you had problems, you did something wrong. This typically signals one has not understood the concepts correctly. And the ideomatic way to use a dynamically allocated 2D array is to use a pointer to a 1D array. Either way, `int **` is the wrong type. `int ***` is complete nonsense. Functions can return a result!

Answer (score 2):

To avoid pointer bugs you just ran into I suggest to simplify your dynamic 2D-array allocation like this ->

```
int (*array) [Y] = malloc(sizeof(int[X][Y]));
```

Access your array like this ->

```
int g=array[0][0];
```

And set like this ->

```
array[0][0]=0;
```

That will simplify your solution a lot and you also get a continuous memory block containing your 2D-array as a bonus. That will also simplify writing and reading files as you do not need to traverse each element if you do not necessarily have to do that for other reasons.

/A

Answer (score 1):

Try modify your function like this:

```
        void readSudokuFile(char* filename, int** grid) {
   // ...
                grid[i][j] = curr;
    }
```

and invoke it like this:

```
readSudokuFile(filename, sudoku)
```